# bin/magento always got killed

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.1

I can't run any bin/magento commands, always got killed. (setup:di:compile, cache:clean, cache:flush, indexer:reindex)

[image: screenshot]

I already changed memory_limit = -1 the php.ini, and tried to run the bin/magento commands with specified memory size; but all return "Killed" like the above picture.

I also tried to clean var/log/* generated/* var/cache/* folders, but still same.

Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Thanks so much

Comment: Just a sidenote if I may: I suggest you don't run any of the bin/magento commands with the **root* user. you should always use same user as the webserver (usually www-data), otherwise you will mess up the permissions.

Comment: thank you, I will be careful

Comment: I am not clear with the answer can you explain more

Answer (score 1):

it's the base_url. I set it to null in database directly, problem is fixed after I added value.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, you can also accept your own answer, to mark it as resolved. Thanks.

Comment: either secure base or unsecure base URL, can you explain little bit more

Answer (score 0):

in my case the problem was because of removed generated/.htaccess